# deque vs vector guidance after C++11 enhancements

Tags: c++, c++11

Back in the pre-C++11 days, many book authors recommended the use of `deque` for situations that called for a dynamically sized container with random access. This was in part due to the fact that `deque` is a move versatile data structure than `vector`, but also it was due to the fact that `vector` in the pre-C++11 world did not offer a convenient way to size down its capacity via "shrink to fit." The greater `deque` overhead of indirect access to elements via the brackets operator and iterators seemed to be subsumed by the greater `vector` overhead of reallocation.

On the other hand, some things haven't changed. `vector` still uses a geometric (i.e., size*factor) scheme for reallocation and stil must copy (or move if possible) all of its elements into the newly allocated space. It is still the same old `vector` with regard to insertion/removal of elements at the front and/or middle. On the other hand, it offers better locality of reference, although if the blocks used by `deque` are a "good large" size, the benefit with regard to caching can be argued for many apps.

So, my question is if in light of the changes that came with C++11, `deque` should continue to remain the go to / first choice container for dynamically sized / random access needs.

Comment: It seems to me that many or most people changed their tune on that debate after a while, long before C++11.  Data locality is just too damn good.

Comment: `vector::shrink_to_fit` is still a non-binding call; implementations are free to ignore it.

Comment: Despite this advice, I primarily use vector unless the size will be 100's mb or the objects very expensive to copy.

Comment: To follow up on @Praetorian from 21.4.4/13: `Remarks: shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size().`

Comment: vector was always my first choice... btw the A to your Q is : use vector by default, dq if you have need for it. :) OFc there is a perf diff, but most of the time you dont care...  When you do - measure :)

Comment: I found it.  Herb Sutter's [GotW #54](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) is probably the most widely known source of the advice to prefer `deque` over `vector`.  But even he changed his mind. http://www.cpptalk.net/image-vp323385.html -- search for his post there

Comment: *Use vectors whenever you can. If you cannot use vectors, redesign your solution so that you can use vectors.* --Alexander Stepanov

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: it's interesting that he changed his mind really. Personally, I sometimes wonder if using (by default) a random access container is such a good idea because if you start relying on random access (rather than thinking about something else), then finding a replacement is either complicated or leads to a lot of necessary refactoring.

Comment: There is a video by Bjarne Stroustrup (creator of C++) on this subjet:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Answer (score 4):

The one language + library change which does make a difference is when you have a non-copyable + non-moveable type (such as a type which contains a `mutex` or an `atomic` variable).  You can store those in a `deque` (via one of the `emplace_`* methods) but cannot store them in a `vector`.

Comment: via `emplace_front` or `emplace_back`.  `emplace` can not be used for this purpose.

Comment: I guess for stable_vector storing nonmovable elements will also work, right ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It would depend on the specific implementation, I know not whether it's been upgraded to C++11 already.

Answer (score 4):

Josuttis's The C++ Standard Library states: (**When to use which container** Sec 7.12)

> By default, you should use a **vector**. It has the simplest internal data
>   structure and provides random access. Thus, data access is convenient
>   and flexible, and data processing is often fast enough.
>
> If you insert and/or remove elements often at the beginning and the
>   end of a sequence, you should  use a **deque**. You should also use a
>   deque if it is important that the amount of internal memory used by
>   the container shrinks when elements are removed. Also, because a
>   vector usually uses one block of memory for its elements, a deque
>   might be able to contain more elements because it uses several blocks.